# Change number of likes for post in tape with ajax, when click like button

Tags: php, ajax

I working with Yii2 Framework and now I want change number of like for post when click like button success by Ajax. Now I refresh page, count of likes changes.

My Ajax button like:

```
$(document).on('click','.like-btn',function(e){
    event.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/site/like',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'id': self.attr('data-id'),
            'type': self.attr('data-type')
        },
        success: function (data){
            if (data.status == 403){
                $('#login').modal('show');
            } else if (data.status == 200){
                if (data.code == 1){
                    let attrCurrent = $("[data-id ="+self.attr('data-id')+"]"+"[data-type ="+self.attr('data-type')+"]");
                    attrCurrent.addClass('liked');
                } else if (data.code == 2) {
                    let attrCurrent = $("[data-id ="+self.attr('data-id')+"]"+"[data-type ="+self.attr('data-type')+"]");
                    attrCurrent.removeClass('liked')
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

For example button like:

```
<div class="box-content box-blog-news">
    <div class="row show_here ">
        <?php foreach ($blog as $value): ?>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 mt-10 mb-10">
            <div class="item-blog-news mb-0">
                <div class="images images-form">
                    <div class="img-item">
                        <div class="img-item"><img ... ></div>
                    </div>
                    <?=LikeArticleWidget::widget([ 'article_id'=> $value->id, 'type' => ArticleLike::TYPE_LIKE_BLOG, 'user_id' => ArticleLike::isLikedBlog(Yii::$app->user->id, $value->id)]); ?>
                </div>
                ...
                <ul class="box-active flex">
                    <li><span class="icon-default icon-heart-2"></span> (
                        <?=$ value->getLike()->count() ?>)
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Like components:

```
<div class="box-like box-like-nobg like-btn <?= $user_id ? 'liked' : 'like' ?>"
     data-id="<?= $article_id ?>"
     data-type="<?= $type ?>"></div>
```

Comment: Hi can show `like-btn` html as well ?

Comment: @Swati I've updated.

Comment: So `<ul class="box-active flex">..` is inside that liked div ? please show proper html code

Comment: @Swati <ul class="box-active flex">.. and <div class="box-like> is separate.

Comment: I think you didn't understood my question i mean to say show proper html code where both divs are shown.

Comment: @Swati yep I've updated

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure with your html structure but you just need to get total count value then using this value `add 1` or `subtract 1` and update same inside your `li` tag.

**Demo Code** :

```js
var data = {
  "code": 1
} //jus for demo...
$(document).on('click', '.like-btn', function(e) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var self = $(this);
  /* $.ajax({
     your ajax code//
     
     */
  //get like count ..
  var likes = parseInt(self.closest(".item-blog-news").find("li").clone().children().remove().end().text().replace(/[()]/g, '').trim())
  if (data.code == 1) {
    let attrCurrent = $("[data-id =" + self.attr('data-id') + "]" + "[data-type =" + self.attr('data-type') + "]");
    attrCurrent.addClass('liked');
    //access li where total count is add 1 to total number.. change icon class.as well..
    self.closest(".item-blog-news").find("li").html("<span class='icon-default icon-heart'></span> (" + (likes + 1) + ")");
  } else if (data.code == 2) {
    let attrCurrent = $("[data-id =" + self.attr('data-id') + "]" + "[data-type =" + self.attr('data-type') + "]");
    attrCurrent.removeClass('liked')
    //access li where total count is sub 1 to total number..
    self.closest(".item-blog-news").find("li").html("<span class='icon-default icon-heart'></span>(" + (likes - 1) + ")");
  }

  /* }
    }
  });*/

})
```

```css
.liked {
  color: red
}

li {
  list-style: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="box-content box-blog-news">
  <div class="row show_here ">

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 mt-10 mb-10">
      <div class="item-blog-news mb-0">
        <div class="images images-form">
          <div class="img-item">
            <div class="img-item"><img ...></div>
          </div>
          <div class="box-like box-like-nobg like-btn <?= $user_id ? 'liked' : 'like' ?>" data-id="1" data-type="something">Like</div>
        </div>
        ...
        <ul class="box-active flex">
          <li><span class="icon-default icon-heart"></span> (24)
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 mt-10 mb-10">
      <div class="item-blog-news mb-0">
        <div class="images images-form">
          <div class="img-item">
            <div class="img-item"><img ...></div>
          </div>
          <div class="box-like box-like-nobg like-btn <?= $user_id ? 'liked' : 'like' ?>" data-id="2" data-type="something">Like</div>
        </div>
        ...
        <ul class="box-active flex">
          <li><span class="icon-default icon-heart"></span> (23)
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```